# iMacros randomly stops in a loop

Tags: imacros

I'm facing a problem that my imacro script just doesn't continue looping and freezes after a couple of loops, did anyone of you already face such problem?

Here's my script:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES
SET !LOADCHECK YES
URL GOTO=http://web.stagram.com/tag/fun/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=2 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=3 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=5 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=6 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8
TAG POS=7 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn.stagram.com/img/like.png
WAIT SECONDS=8

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
```

Comment: Yes. That can happen with simple iim files. Try with JS scripting . There are examples on stackoverflow how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u miss this line of code

SET !LOOP 1