# How to Loop imacro script using batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file, imacros

My code looks like this in .bat file

```
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim" -loop 3
timeout /t 120
```

But problem is I am not able to loop my `loop-google-ad-word.iim` script 3 times from batch file it runs just once normally.

I referred http://wiki.imacros.net/Example-Batchfile.bat here and did similarly.
Also referred [iMacros randomly stops in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519024/imacros-randomly-stops-in-a-loop) but it does not loop

Any related suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code helps me to loop batch file so in this loop I also added the code to delete 1st row of csv file from which my imacro reads data, so automatically imacro will get next row data at each loop.

Also No. of times it should loop i have made dynamic depending on the lines in my csv file. So it first counts no. of lines and then passes it to for loop `%cnt%`

```
@echo It will count no.of lines in file and pass the count 2for loop
set file=C:\Users\account\Documents\iMacros\adwords-filename.csv
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo %file% has %cnt% lines
timeout /t 5

@echo Loop starts now-------------------
for /L %%A in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    @echo call macro script
    start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim"
    timeout /t 60

    @echo delete 1st line of csv file at each loop
    set "csv=C:\Users\account\Documents\iMacros\adwords-filename.csv"
    more +1 "%csv%" >"%csv%.new"
    move /y "%csv%.new" "%csv%" >nul
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the batch file to loop?

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do (
    start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim"
    timeout /t 120
)
```

Comment: No change, it still runs only once it does not loops @SomethingDark

Comment: @somethingDark I guess this is a batch loop and what the user want is to put the loop for imacro.

Comment: This is a batch loop. Kinjal was complaining about the iMacro loop not working, so I was trying out a workaround.

Comment: I want to call macro script from a batch file, and this script shall loop n no. of times let's say 3 times. 
And i cannot loop batch file n times as my macro script calls excel sheet at each loop and takes data from a column so at every loop there will a a next row data.

Hope it clears my question

Comment: That actually makes it MORE complicated. I don't see how calling the macro in a loop and adding the loop as an argument could possibly have different results. You're only putting the one line in a loop.

Comment: This could be related to http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support - Firefox must be running before you run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you use batch script you can construct a code like this for an infinite loop!

```
@echo off

:Intro
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim" -loop 3
timeout /t 120
goto Intro

quit
```

Ok, this uses a simple goto command, hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion to have an .iim Macro loop 3 times after being launched from a .BAT File is to put the following Statement at the beginning of your Macro (+ Adjust '!DATASOURCE_LINE' by 2 or 3 if your Macro uses a Datasource...):

```
SET !LOOP -1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
ADD !DATASOURCE_LINE 2
```

And your .BAT File will look like this:

```
start /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim"
timeout /t 120
```

(I use it myself...)